# If statement against 2 data tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 data tables one which records the date of an order and the other records the delivery date of an order if a delivery schedule is created.
I want to write a query to look at the table with the delivery schedule and bring me a date back if there is one there, if there isn't i want it to pick up the date of the order.

I tried this query

```
SELECT POS_DELIVERY_DATE 
from POS_SCH 
where POS_CONTRACT = {Contract} and POS_ORDER = {Order} and POS_LINE = {Line}
ELSE
SELECT POH_DEL_DATE 
from POH_HFM 
Where POH_CONTRACT = {Contract} and POH_ORDER = {Order}
```

I'm getting the following error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near '}'. Msg 102,
> Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near '}'.

Comment: What RDBMS?  I don't know any db that uses curly brackets.  Is `{Contract}` referring to a column?

Comment: In the title you reference an `IF` statement. Are you missing some parts to you query?

Comment: @lemon I may be wrong here, but I think the `IF` was an attempt by OP to frame their issue in terms of procedural code, where in set based code/sql this is solved through a LEFT or FULL outer join and a COALESCE.

Comment: Yes I've figured it out: was about to publish the answer till realizing you just wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

There's two issues:

1. Your specific question and its solution (Joining the two tables in a single `FROM` clause and using a `COALESCE()` in your `SELECT`)
2. These curly braces that are throwing the error.

For number 1 it's going to look like:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(POS_SCH.POS_DELIVERY_DATE, POH_FHM.POH_DEL_DATE) as POSPOH_DEL_DATE
FROM POS_SCH 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN POH_HFM
       ON POS_SCH.POS_CONTRACT = POH_HFM.POH_CONCTRACT
       AND POS_SCH.POS_ORDER = POH_HFM.POH_ORDER
WHERE 
    POS_SCH.POS_CONTRACT = {Contract} 
    and POS_SCH.POS_ORDER = {Order} 
    and POS_SCH.POS_LINE = {Line};
```

Here we are joining the two tables on Order and Contract, to mimic what you were doing in the two `WHERE` clauses. Once joined, we use the `COALESCE()` function that tells sql-server to use the `POS_SCH.POS_DELIVERY_DATE` unless it's `NULL`, in which case use the `POH_FHM.POH_DEL_DATE` instead.

Since we can't see your data and you haven't shared sample data, this logic is a bit of a guess. But this should work if every order/line is present in your `POS_SCH` table. If, however, an Order (or Order Line) might not be present in `POS_SCH` where it could be present in `POH_HFM` than a `FULL OUTER JOIN` or your RDBMS's equivalent would be necessary, as well as a small rewrite of the WHERE clause.

As for issue number 2 and your error, you `{something}` isn't supported by your RDBMS, so whatever tokenization is supposed to be happening there isn't working the way you think it is.

Answer (score -1):

You want to check if exists so, Why don't use Inner Join? Its seems more logical when you want to look at two tables at the same time. Im understanding that the {something} are variables that you deleted to protect the data but... idk if that is correct because it can be null. If I miss correct/edit me.

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT POS_DELIVERY_DATE
            FROM POS_SCH
            WHERE POS_CONTRACT = {Contract} AND POS_ORDER = {Order} AND POS_LINE = {Line}
        ) THEN (
            SELECT POS_DELIVERY_DATE
            FROM POS_SCH
            WHERE POS_CONTRACT = {Contract} AND POS_ORDER = {Order} AND POS_LINE = {Line}
        )
        ELSE (
            SELECT POH_DEL_DATE
            FROM POH_HFM
            WHERE POH_CONTRACT = {Contract} AND POH_ORDER = {Order}
        )
    END AS selected_date;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gegob that query has worked :) Really appreciate you resolving this for me

Comment: Im happy that it worked to you but I think you will need try to use the upvote question